# Single or persistent connection oracle/php

Tags: php, oracle

Create a single connection using it between various php scripts.

Hello everyone.  I need to continuously process data from an oracle database.  This data is processed by various pages in PHP to which users connect.  The problem is that each php script has its own connection, with related queries and data processing.

Example:

page1.php

```
//...
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'password'', $server);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    // bla bla bla
}
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM table1');
oci_execute($stid);
//data processing
oci_close($conn);
//...
```

page2.php

```
//...
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'password'', $server);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    // bla bla bla
}
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM table2');
oci_execute($stid);
//data processing
oci_close($conn);
//...
```

and so on...

The problem is that in doing so I go to weigh down the log of the Oracle server connections. I created a PHP script that creates the single connection and in loop performs all the query necessary to download the data on a MySQL database.
This connection is never closed, except for programmed closures or errors.
This script is launched by Cron on a Ubuntu server.

conn.php

```
//...
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'password'', $server);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    // bla bla bla
}else{
    while ($stop) {
        //..
        // download oracle data and upload in mysql
        //..
        sleep(10);
    }
    oci_close($connessione_oracle);
}
```

So as to connect all the php pages to the mysql database.  I have no limits or restrictions on my sql database.  But if it were possible I would like to process the data coming directly from the Oracle database, using a single connection.  I read that there is a way to create persistent connections, but I didn't quite understand how to apply it.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your exact problem is? Does your code not work? Are you using multiple database connections at the same time? Your question sounds very much like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `The problem is that I have to be "forced", by necessity, to create a single connection to the database`...it's not clear what you mean. Are you saying that the oracle database will only accept a single simultaneous connection to it from your account? What happens if you open a connection, leave it open, and then connect again?

Comment: I would like to create a single connection to the Oracle database so that each PHP page uses that connection to perform all queries.

Comment: It's still not very clear what the real problem is. Maybe it is that you haven't heard of [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)? So you can open the database connection, and then include all the PHP scripts you have to transfer the data.

Comment: I have to create a PHP script that creates a connection to the Oracle databse.
This connection must never close, except for programmed errors or closings.
The script would be launched on Ubuntu server.
Each PHP page that needs to withdraw data from the Oracle server should take advantage of that already open connection and not create others.
The problem is only this.

Comment: `This connection must never close`...why? This seems like an arbitrary restriction. What is the overall reason for that? I am starting to smell an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: `in doing so I go to weigh down the log of the Oracle server connections`...so it creates some log entries when you make a new connection? Why is _that_ a problem??

Comment: As already written in the post:
"The problem is that in doing so i go to weigh down the log of the Oracle Server Connections."
The Oracle server is not my property, it is corporate.
The systemist told me that creating multiple connections I go to weigh down the log of connections, going to cause possible crashes if the size of the log reaches the maximum limit destined for me.
And he advised me to create a single connection without ever closing it and making the only connection exploit to all the PHP pages.

Comment: From [what I read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.connection.php) you can simply swap `oci_connect()` for `oci_pconnect()` to get a persistent oracle connection. Is that problematic?

Comment: Yes, I also read of Oci_Connect.
But how can I say to all the other PHP pages to use that open connection with Oci_PConnect?

Comment: As long as you use the same credentials for the database, PHP will cache the connection for you when you use [oci_pconnect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-pconnect.php). You can verify this by checking the database logs.

Comment: `if the size of the log reaches the maximum limit destined for me`...sorry but this is the system admin's problem, not yours - they should allocate a log size appropriate for the type of work the account is doing, and make sure it's rotated out frequently so it doesn't get too big. Telling you to make workarounds in your code to mitigate for the inefficient way they administer their server is totally the wrong approach. Typical beauracratic/lazy corporate nonsense. And the Oracle account PHP is using should be specifically for the use of the PHP application, not for you personally.

Comment: However, as KIKO mentioned this problem may already be solved by the oci drivers anyway - like I said earlier, have you actually tested this? As the oci_pconnect documentation which KIKO provided you with says: _"Persistent connections are cached and re-used between requests, resulting in reduced overhead on each page load; a typical PHP application will have a single persistent connection open against an Oracle server per Apache child process (or PHP FPM process). See the OCI8 Connection Handling and Connection Pooling section for more information."_

Comment: Just to explain our resistance to your question a bit: It is normal for each PHP request to create their own database connection. That's just how PHP works. Especially when using MySQL it can cause all sorts of problems when you try to use a persistent connection. Here an Oracle database is different. Also, from your response it is not completely clear you understand that you need to replace `oci_connect()` by `oci_pconnect()` in **all** your PHP pages.

Comment: I tried to change oci_connect with oci_pconnect but nothing changes, every time it is run from a php page it creates a new connection :(

Comment: You have this evidence from the Oracle database logs? Did you change _all_ instances of `oci_connect` in your code to `oci_pconnect`? Also note that the shared connection is, says the manual, _"per Apache child process (or PHP FPM process)"_ . So are you sure that you are using a single Apache/FPM process for your tests?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.connection.php also says _"The oci_pconnect() cache is cleared and any database connections closed when the PHP process terminates, so effective use of persistent connections requires that PHP be an Apache module or used with FPM, or similar. Persistent connections will not have any benefits over oci_connect() when PHP is used with CGI or via the command-line"_ . So please check your setup carefully.

Comment: First of all, it is silly for a DBA to complain about "logs" - by which he/she must mean audit trail. That is a DBA responsibility and unless you're making millions of connections per day really should not be an issue. If you *are* making that quantity of connections then you do have an architectural problem - PHP wasn't meant for that kind of processing. You'd be better off moving data processing into the database itself with PL/SQL. But if those connections are coming from human users clicking on things, the volume would be minimal and you should not be told to maintain a single connection.

Comment: Also, I've never heard of a DBA allocating a "maximum limit" to some kind of log. There's no limit to audit entries. There's no space allocated by user that is used by multiple connections. There is a way to limit concurrent # of connections but that has nothing to do with any log and wouldn't be a problem if your connections are serial. I think you were sold a story.

Comment: PaulW is absolutely right - similar to what I was saying earlier. IMO either your DBA is incompetent or they just can't be bothered to help you properly. This should not be a problem that needs to be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use persistent OCI8 or PDO connections to improve certain performances of you scripts, but this will only be useful within a single PHP page, not shared between several scripts, which in any case is not recommended.

To answer your first question: **the log problem is nonsense**. It's simply a matter of your DBA being able to manage Oracle Archive/Redo Logs and purge them if necessary.

Can't you output any debug messages because the Php or Apache log is growing on the filesysem? Of course not... Well, it's the same for Oracle.